# Understanding a proof that $[L : L^G] = |G|$ when $G$ acts faithfully on a field $L$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory, extension-field, group-actions

I'm trying to wrap my head around a proof in my lecturer's Galois theory notes, but am struggling to see why a particular step follows from what came before it. [I've attached a screenshot to save me copying out the whole proof (it's quite long, and it's only a very small part I'm having trouble with).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BncNd.png)

I'm struggling to see how the very last step follows: I can't see how from (3) you can can deduce that $\sum \alpha_i\frac{\beta_i}{\beta_1} = 0$  Presumably you take $g_j$ to be the identity so that you get $\alpha_i$ out, but when you substitute in $g(\beta_i) = \frac{\beta_i}{\beta_1}g(\beta_1)$ you're left with a $g(\beta_1)$ that doesn't feature in the given sum.

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain what I'm missing or, if there's some kind of mistake in the proof, what I could do to fix it.

Comment: $L/L^G$ is a [finite separable extension so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem#Constructive_results) $L=L^G(a)$, then the minimal polynomial of $a$ is $f(x)=\prod_{g\in G} (x-g(a))\in L^G[x]$ so $[L:L^G]=\deg(f)=|G|$